# How to display limited wordpress categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want limit number of categories that are displaying, problem is that it uses not default wordpress (it uses theme code that I have) code a.k.a names that I don't know and google does not found.

So for example this code displays all the categories:

```
<?php echo cp_create_categories_list( 'dir' ); ?>
```

**How can I limit number of categories that are displaying?**

I have tried combine this with default wordpress code:

```
    <?php
// display 7 random categories
$cats ='';
$categories=get_categories('exclude=' . $GLOBALS[asides_id]);
$rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 7);
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
$cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';
}
wp_list_categories('title_li=&include='.$cats);
?>
```

But I didn't got any success with it maybe because of lack of knowledge or it simply does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code like this

```
<?php
// display 7 random categories
$cats ='';
$categories=get_categories('posts_per_page=5&exclude=' . $GLOBALS[asides_id]);
$rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 7);
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
$cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';
}
wp_list_categories('title_li=&include='.$cats);
?>
```

Comment: further details please check this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories